# Is it possible to add a system name to a BPMN activity in Visio 2013

Tags: process, visio, bpmn

I am creating a Business Process Flow in Viso 2013 professional. I have created several activities int he flow. Each of the activities are performed by a different system and I would like to some how display that system name within the activity box, or atleast an abbreviation of the system name. Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could simply add the system name manually before the task (activity) labels. This is for sure not a very elegant solution.

What you are doing is assigning the tasks to generic roles or specific process participants and for this one usually uses pools and lanes, as *suggested* by the [BPMN 2.0 Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/) page 306 f (336 f in PDF).
The downside is that using a pool or a lane for each process participant can get messy if many different participants need to be specified.

That's where the work-around suggested above comes into play, at least when using Visio, as Visio's BPMN modeling capabilities are rather limited. Many other tools support BPMN 2.0 attributes or special BPMN extension elements for such cases (I know Signavio supports both, but [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Business_Process_Modeling_Notation_tools) for an overview over all tools).